# Get data through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the fallowing entities:

`User has_many Projects`

`Project has_many ProjectKeywords`

`Keyword has_many ProjectKeywords`

`Project and Keyword has_many Reports`

I want to display a data chart in one of my pages, but I don't know how to display the `reports`  for the `Projects` owned by a `User`. This is how I display my rows from `Result` table right now.

`Reports controller:`

```
def self.chart_data(start = 1.weeks.ago) 
  total_possitions = possition_by_day(start)
  possitions_top_fiftys = where("possition < ?", 50).possition_by_day(start)
   (start.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
   {
    created_at: date,
    possitions_top_fifty: possitions_top_fiftys[date] || 0,
   }
  end
end

def self.possition_by_day(start)
  results = unscoped.where(created_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
  results = results.group("date(created_at)")
  results = results.order("date(created_at)")
  results = results.select("date(created_at) as created_at, count(*) as count")
  results.each_with_object({}) do |result, possitions|
   possitions[result.created_at.to_date] = result.count
  end
```

end

Comment: have you tried `user_projects = Project.where("user_id = ?", current_user)` and then `user_projects.first.reports`?  you may need to change `current_user` but something like that should work

Comment: also, are you using rails 3 or rails 4?  you can't have both...

Comment: I am using, rails 4 and thank you

Comment: Alex, did that work for you?  If so, I'll add it answer

Answer (score 1):

In `reports_controller`

```
before_filter :user_projects

#to find reports for a specific project
def project_reports(project)
  this_project = @user_projects.where("id = ?", project.id)
  this_project.reports
end

def user_projects
  @user_projects = Project.where("user_id = ?", current_user)
end
```

In your `view`

```
<%= @report.project_reports(@project) %>
#=> reports associated with this user's specific project
```

or

```
<% @user_projects.each do |project| %>
  <% project.reports.each do |report|
    <%= #report stuff here %>
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
#=> loops through each of the user's projects and shows the report how you wish
```